# How to get url on fetch network error

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I need to issue fetch requests to multiple (up to 80) microHTTP servers, some of which may not be running. In those cases, fetch responds with a network error. Is there a way to associated the error with the original URL?

Here are the HTML page, the Javascript file (from which I removed most of the business related statements), and the console messages. But first, to reiterate, what I am hoping to discover is how to either trap the network error some place other than the "catch" block or how to access some structure in the "catch" block that contains the URL. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "//w3c//dtd html 4.01 Tradional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose/dtd">
<!--               Copyright Siemens AG 2018        -->
<!--  Main Web page for FCUD Overview Display.      -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Port Overview</title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <!--- define the port table -->
      <table id="porttable" border>
          <thead>
              <tr><th>Port</th>
                  <th>Last Update</th>
                  <th>data1</th>
                  <th>data2</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
    <script src="js/fetchExample.js"></script>
</html>
```

The Javascript file fetchExample.js:

```
const numberOfPorts = 5;          // set to 5, but in production 80
const portIncrement = 50000;
var   Host = "pickahost";         // the hostname of the server running the http servers


//  MyPort class.
function MyPort (Json) {          // MyPort Constructor
    console.log("Creating Port object - " + Json.ObjectName);
    this.ObjectName = Json.ObjectName;
    this.fetchInProgress = false;
    // there are many more properties, too.
    // end of MyPort constructor
}; // end of MyPort class definition


function pollForUpdates (test) {
    console.log('Starting polling pass ' + test + ": " + Date().toLocaleString() + " (" + Date.now() + ")");
    var urlHost = "http://" + Host + ":"

    for (port = 1; port <= numberOfPorts; port++) {
        thisPort = ports[port];
        console.log("  Polling " + thisPort.ObjectName + (thisPort.fetchInProgress
                                                                     ? "  fetch in progress!" 
                                                                     : " now"));
        if (! thisPort.fetchInProgress) {
            // Check for identify updates.
            var urlPort = urlHost + (port + portIncrement) + "/identify";
            console.log('    requesting url=' + urlPort);
            thisPort.fetchInProgress = true;
            fetch(urlPort)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log("Received response from GET of " + response.url);
                var portOffset = response.url.indexOf(":5") + 1;
                var portIndex = parseInt(response.url.slice(portOffset,portOffset+5)) - portIncrement;
                ports[portIndex].fetchInProgress = false;
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    // Examine the text in the response
                    response.json()
                    .then(function(data) {
                        console.log("  json results:", data.ObjectName);
                        var portIndex = parseInt(data.ObjectName.slice(4));
                        // save data from GET request ...
                        console.log("  stashed port (" + portIndex + ") - " + data.ObjectName + ": " + port[portIndex]);
                        } ).then (function() {displayDataRows(); return;} )
                } // end of if {status == 200}

                else {
                    response.json() 
                    .then(function(data) {
                        console.log("  json results:", data.ObjectName);
                        var portIndex = parseInt(data.ObjectName.slice(4));
                        // save data from GET request ...
                        console.log("  stashed ports (" + portIndex + ") - " + data.ObjectName + ": " + ports[portIndex]);
                        } ).then (function() {displayDataRows(); return;} );
                } // end of else {status != 200}
            } ) // end of then call

            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
            } )
        } // end of if (! thisPort.fetchInProgress)
    } // end of for port

    // There is logic here to restart pollForUpdates after a delay, but the question relates to the fetch and catch
} // end of pollForUpdates


// Main program
console.log('starting PortStatus.js');
ports = new Array(numberOfPorts);

for (p=1; p<=numberOfPorts; ++p) {
    var ObjName = "port" + ("0" + p).slice(-2);
    ports[p] = new MyPort({ObjectName: ObjName});
}

testing = 0;
pollForUpdates(++testing);
console.log("pollForUpdates has returned to the main program.");
console.log('exiting fetchExample.js');
```

The console output:

```
starting PortStatus.js
fetchExample.js:69:1
Creating Port object - port01
fetchExample.js:8:5
Creating Port object - port02
fetchExample.js:8:5
Creating Port object - port03
fetchExample.js:8:5
Creating Port object - port04
fetchExample.js:8:5
Creating Port object - port05
fetchExample.js:8:5
Starting polling pass 1: Sat Jul 14 2018 22:58:11 GMT-0500 (CDT) (1531627091876)
fetchExample.js:17:5
  Polling port01 now
fetchExample.js:22:9
    requesting url=http://pickahost:50001/identify
fetchExample.js:28:13
  Polling port02 now
fetchExample.js:22:9
    requesting url=http://pickahost:50002/identify
fetchExample.js:28:13
  Polling port03 now
fetchExample.js:22:9
    requesting url=http://pickahost:50003/identify
fetchExample.js:28:13
  Polling port04 now
fetchExample.js:22:9
    requesting url=http://pickahost:50004/identify
fetchExample.js:28:13
  Polling port05 now
fetchExample.js:22:9
    requesting url=http://pickahost:50005/identify
fetchExample.js:28:13
pollForUpdates has returned to the main program.
fetchExample.js:79:1
exiting fetchExample.js
fetchExample.js:80:1
Fetch Error :-S 
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
fetchExample.js:59:17
Fetch Error :-S 
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
fetchExample.js:59:17
Fetch Error :-S 
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
fetchExample.js:59:17
Fetch Error :-S 
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
fetchExample.js:59:17
Fetch Error :-S 
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
fetchExample.js:59:17
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What does your code look like? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure how to show you my code. All I see on the web page is "Ask Question" and "Add Comment". When I try to insert my code, I get an error saying the comment is 660 characters too long. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Just [edit] your question. Make sure to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you make request and response is not valid like 404 error code in this case url is found in response, but sometimes you have no internet or other things you won't recessive response or you will recessive it after long time in this case write a wrapper for fetch and control error massage from it. 

 you should do like this

```
 fetch(url, options) {
    let link=url;
    let retries = 3;
    let retryDelay = 1000;
    let timeout = 4000;

    if (options && options.retries) {
        retries = options.retries;
    }
    if (options && options.timeout) {
        timeout = options.timeout;
    }
    if (options && options.retryDelay) {
        retryDelay = options.retryDelay;
    }
    let timeoutCallBack = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(reject, timeout, 'request timeout');
    });

    return Promise
        .race([timeoutCallBack, new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            let wrappedFetch = function (n) {
                fetch(url, options)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.ok)
                            resolve(response);
                        else throw error('bad error code' + link)
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        if (n > 0) {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                wrappedFetch(--n);
                            }, retryDelay);
                        } else {
                            reject(error+link);//here you send change error massage
                        }
                    });
            };
            wrappedFetch(retries);
        })]);

     };
```

then you can export this module and in your js file simply import it it will work.

PS: i use my own write fetch , when you won't receive any response you should add timeout

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it does not answer the question. Dealing with an error response from the HTTP server is well documented. My question is about "network errors" where the host or the port is not responding, so there is no HTTP response code. In that case, I want to know the URL of the original request, that is, the URL that was not found. Is this possible?

Comment: now i understand your question. i think of writing a wrapper for fetch and from there pass url in error massage i updated the answer